# How to delete older files and keep last day files for each month in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, datetime

I need to retain the backup file started on 31st april and ended next day May 1.
backup timings differ for each folder, but the backup files are identical

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a way to solve your problem : `os.path.getctime` getting the date of creation of the file and `os.path.getmtime` getting the date of last modification of the file

```
import os

if os.path.getctime("test.txt") > os.path.getctime("test2.txt"):
    print("test.txt is more recent")
    os.remove("test2.txt")
else:
    print("test2.txt is more recent")
    os.remove("test.txt")
```